# How do I sleep my computer from within python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I'm on a Mac and I'd like to be able to sleep my computer from a python script. I can do it in bash with this command:

```sh
/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend
```

I read the instructions on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python) post and followed the instructions, but I ran into the following error.

```py
import subprocess    
subprocess.Popen("/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend")
```

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   '/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\
>   Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend':
>   '/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\
>   Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend'

Comment: What code did you try? The problem is probably the extra `\' and the fact that you pass the "-suspend" parameter as the executable file name

Comment: I'll add it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
import subprocess    
subprocess.run(["/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession",
                "-suspend"])
```

You have to provide an existing path without escapes required by the shell (so "Menu\ Extras" -> "Menu Extras") as the first parameter, and pass the other parameters separately.

Comment: for more complicated commands shlex is nice.
`subprocess.run(shlex.split("/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend"))`